# How to hide EGL surface contents when the native window is unmapped under Wayland?

Tags: gtk, egl, wayland

We do something like this (simplified) in our code:

```cpp
auto surface = gdk_wayland_window_get_wl_surface(window);
auto wlSurface = wl_compositor_create_surface(m_wlCompositor);
auto wlEGLWindow = wl_egl_window_create(wlSurface, width, height);
auto eglSurface = eglCreatePlatformWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, wlEGLWindow, nullptr);
```

and then use this surface as usual, e.g. call `eglSwapBuffers()` on it.

This works fine, but when the window (identified by `GdkWindow* window` in the code above) is hidden, e.g. because the user switches to another page of the `GtkNotebook` containing it, the surface remains displayed.

What is the correct way to hide it when the window is hidden and show it back when it becomes visible again?

I've tried resizing the window to 0*0 size in "unmap" GTK callback, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.